# Parse HTML file using Python without external module

Tags: python, jenkins, attributeerror, jenkins-cli, html-parser

I am trying to Parse a html file using Python without 
using any external module. The reason is I am triggering
a jenkins job and running into some import issues with
lxml and BeautifulSoup (tried resolving it and I think
somewhere I am doing over engineering to get my stuff done)

**Input**:

```
    <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="a.html">BA</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.000s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="o.html">Aa</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.000s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="g.html">VideoAds</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.390s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="suite">
    <td colspan="2" class="totalLabel">Total</td>

        <td class="zero number">271</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">3</td>

    <td class="passRate suite">
            98%
          </td>

  </tr>
```

**Output**:

I want to take that specific block
of tr tag with the class "suite" (check at the end) and then pull
the values for Zero number, Zero number, Zero number
and passRate suite. Finally, print the values.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Eg. Zero number = 271
...

Pass rate = 98%

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is what I tried with lxml:

```
tree = parse(HTML_FILE)
tds = tree.xpath("//tr[@class='suite']//td/text()")
val = map(str.strip, tds)
```

This works out locally but I really want to do something
without any external dependencies. Shall I use strip() or
open a file using os.path.isFile(). I may not be correct but advise/walk me through what would be solution to do this.

Comment: how about using stdlib? https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser

Comment: isnt that a seperate module again? HTMLParser? I have not had any experience with this before. Maybe you could walk me.

Comment: to get only one element from HTML you could use `re` or even standard string functions.

Comment: I could but the thing is I need to take out that tr block with class = "suite" and then fetch the values. Any alternative/ideas that you can think of?

Comment: @furas : Can you show me how do you do via re?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one element you could try to use `re` module or even string functions.

```
data = '''<tr class="test">
<td class="test">
<a href="no.html">track</a></td>
<td class="duration">0.390s</td>
<td class="zero number">0</td>
<td class="zero number">0</td>
<td class="zero number">0</td>
<td class="passRate">N/A</td></tr>

<tr class="suite">
<td colspan="2" class="totalLabel">Total</td>
<td class="passed number">271</td>
<td class="zero number">0</td>
<td class="failed number">3</td>
<td class="passRate suite">98%</td>
</tr>'''

# re module

import re

print(re.search('suite">(\d+)%', data).group(1))

# string functions

before = 'passRate suite">'
after  = '%'
start = data.find(before) + len(before)
stop  = data.find(after, start)

print(data[start:stop])
```

---

EDIT: to get othere values with `re`

```
import re

print('passed:', re.search('passed number">(\d+)', data).group(1))
print('zero:', re.search('zero number">(\d+)', data).group(1))
print('failed:', re.search('zero number">(\d+)', data).group(1))
print('Rate:', re.search('suite">(\d+)', data).group(1))

passed: 271
zero: 0
failed: 0
Rate: 98
```

Comment: I have few questions:   1. Why does the solution prints 98 twice?        2. If I have to print other values from class = "suite", do I need to repeatedly declare before and after var's ....I tried this: r = re.compile('<tr class="suite"></tr>') after your suggestions but the way you did sounds correct. How do I get the rest of the data from suite class?

Comment: it prints twice because there are two solutions. first with `re` and second with string functions.

Comment: This `before` and `after` works only with value in your question. if you need different values you have to use different `before` and `after` - or different value in `re.search`.

Comment: thanks.. I am not that familiar with the regex...how do you apply re.search on passed number, zero number and failed number to print values of 271, 0 and 3 in that suite class ?

Comment: see example in answer. If you have more than one  `passed number`, `zero number` and `failed number` in file you get more results.

Comment: thanks man, I will definitely look into this more. I have some more to parse but your walkthrough was helpful

Comment: BTW: did you try other xml parser than `lxml` ? There are parsers in standard library - `xml.etree`, `xml.dom`, `xml.dom.minimum` - https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/markup.html . xml parser can be better solution if you will need something more complicated.

Comment: Tried BeautifulSoup and lxml till now. However, I will check with etree and dom if I run into some issues

Comment: I have modified the question and now wondering how do I work with regular expressions / string functions. The way I think is do I need to take out that <tr> tag block with suite = class. What would be the good approach?

Comment: what is the problem ? new lines - "\n" ? For string functions you need only remove spaces and "\n" - so you need only `strip()` - `print(data[start:stop].strip())`

Comment: for `re` you need to find `spaces` and `\n` many times - `[ \n]+` or `\s+` - `print(re.search('suite">[ \n]+(\d+)', data).group(1))` or `print(re.search('suite">\s+(\d+)', data).group(1))`

Comment: If you see there are <td> tags in each block and there are multiple occurrences of <td> tags with a class = "zero number" in different blocks. How do I use re and string functions to take out that specific block of <tr> tag with class = "suite". I have modified the **input and facing some issues with your solution. I just want the ouput like "Passed = 271 ...next line Zero = 0...failed = 0...rate = 98...", correct me if I am wrong somwhere

Comment: I have modified the input and see my above comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

f = open(HTML_FILE)
data = f.read()
before = '<td colspan="2" class="totalLabel">Total</td>'
after  = '%<'
start = data.find(before) + len(before)
stop  = data.find(after, start)

suite_filter = data[start:stop].strip()

RATE_PASS = re.search('suite">[ \n]+(\d+)', suite_filter).group(1)
PASS_COUNT = re.search('passed number">(\d+)', suite_filter).group(1)
SKIPPED_COUNT = re.search('zero number">(\d+)', suite_filter).group(1)

FAIL_COUNT = re.search('failed number">(\d+)', suite_filter).group(1)

TESTS_TOTAL = int(PASS_COUNT) + int(SKIPPED_COUNT) + int(FAIL_COUNT)

print RATE_PASS, PASS_COUNT, SKIPPED_COUNT, TESTS_TOTAL
```

Here is my solution as per the suggestions from @furas. Any improvements/suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I am trying to trigger such a python script on jenkins job and running into an error: 
  File "file.py", line 195, in printHeader
    printCount()
  File "file.py", line 103, in printCount
    PASS_COUNT = re.search('passed number">(\d+)', suite_filter.decode('utf-8')).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' ...i tried decoding the suite_filter as you can see in the error. Any clue on why I am getting attrerror and how do you resolve that?