# Specific HTML block fetch and parse using Regular Expression (Python)

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to Parse a html file using Python without using any external module. The reason is I am triggering a jenkins job and running into some import issues with lxml and BeautifulSoup (tried resolving it and I think
somewhere I am doing over engineering to get my stuff done)

**Input**:

```
    <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="a.html">BA</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.000s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="o.html">Aa</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.000s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="test">
    <td class="test">
      <a href="g.html">GG</a>
    </td>
    <td class="duration">
      0.390s
    </td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

    <td class="passRate">
            N/A
          </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="suite">
    <td colspan="2" class="totalLabel">Total</td>

        <td class="zero number">271</td>

        <td class="zero number">0</td>

        <td class="fail number">3</td>

        <td class="zero number">4</td>


    <td class="passRate suite">
            98%
          </td>

  </tr>
```

**Output**:

I want to take that specific block of tr tag with the class "suite" (check at the end) and then pull the values for all the td tags and assign too.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Eg. The output will be: 
271
   0
     3
       4
         98%
```

Finally I want to assign these values to the variables...so my final output will be:
    A = 271
    B = 0
    C = 3
    D = 4
    D = 98%

(all variables in new lines)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is what I tried with lxml:

```
tree = parse(HTML_FILE)
tds = tree.xpath("//tr[@class='suite']//td/text()")
val = map(str.strip, tds)
```

This works out locally but I really want to do something without any external dependencies. Shall I use strip() or open a file using os.path.isFile(). I may not be correct but advise/walk me through what would be solution to do this.

**The most difficult part that I can think of is "in the last tr tag block of my input, couple of the sub td tags have class = zero number" and so how do you solve it.

**the approach I could think of is take out that block and then remove all the tags except the content and then assign line by line. However, I am not good at regular expressions.

This is not the duplicate of [Parse HTML file using Python without external module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166779/parse-html-file-using-python-without-external-module/) ...this is a different input and different output expected question.

Comment: Why do you need to do without any external dependencies?

Comment: @alecxe I will be triggering a jenkins job for automation stuff and so, in order to use external dependencies such as lxml, BeautifulSoup which are no-doubt useful, I will need to setup virtual env to do pip install. It will involve an overhead of configuring all of my 20 slave machines to support virtual env. So, I really want to do this with regular expressions....

Comment: Guys any suggestions on how to solve the question using regular expressions?